# Banco de dados externo e interno

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Eu sou iniciante em programação `Android` e estou com uma dúvida... é possível uma mesma aplicação ter um banco de dados interno e externo ao msm tempo?

Por exemplo algumas informações são guardadas de forma interna onde o usuário pode ter acesso a qualquer momento e um outro banco de dados onde ele só pode acessar quando estiver online. agradeço desde já...

Comment: Internamente `SQLIte`, externamente `WebService` + Banco de dados da sua preferência.

Comment: E é possível ultizar os dois dentro de uma única aplicação???

Comment: Sim claro, com o `WebService` terá um pouco mais trabalho já que terá que aprender novos conceitos.

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder minhas dúvidas, estou bem interessado e pretendo aprender bastante nessa área... agradecido

Comment: Boa sorte, bons estudos e siga em frente.